# Main form mislinking to subform after switching to Sharepoint back end - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

Why would my form/subform mislink records using SharePoint List back end?

I have years of experience with MS Access, but this is my first time with SharePoint List as a back end.

I developed a small database for a small non-profit.  Started off with Access 365 front end and back end, located on one user's computer.  This ran fine and correctly for a few months, and last month we migrated the back end to SharePoint Lists so that two other users can use the database.  They each have the front end on their desktop.

There's a bound form, Events, linked to tblEvents.  Subform, subVolTime, on this form is linked to tblVolTime, to show the volunteers and how much time they spent at the event. In the subform property, Link Master Fields is set to tblEvents.ID; Link Child Fields is set to tblVolTime.EventID.  There's no extra VBA code.

We migrated to SharePoint Lists using the wizards, and did nothing else.  Shortly afterwards, my user noticed that the wrong people were showing up under events.  He can tell just by looking at the names.

I created an audit query, and I can see that in some cases the dateAdded (date the record was created) in tblVolTime is BEFORE the dateAdded of the event in tblEvent.  This can't be right, because you must have a record in tblEvent before an associated record in tblVolTime.

For example, there's an event ID 261, created on 4 Nov 2021.  The records for the volunteers linked with this eventID were created 7 Oct 2021.  Something went wonky.

Any suggestions are welcome.  My ideas include: unbind the form; hide the subform until the event record is saved; create the event record before the user actually adds any data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, hard to tell. However, unlike moving Access data say to SQL server?

Moving data up to SharePoint is VERY MUCH a different process. Why?

Well, for one, when moving data to SharePoint, the auto number PK's you have (and you MUST HAVE FOR ALL TABLES) are often re-numbered.

Now, due to this re-numbering of auto numbers?

Well, that means before you migrate the data, you BETTER really, but really and beyond really sure  that a relationship was setup between such tables.

In the case of Access, while in most cases we do have a correctly setup relatonship, to be honest, you REALLY never had to do that. In other words, if I setup a master link and child link for a sub form? Well, access would just generate the PK autonumbers for the main table, generate the pk autonumbers for the child table. And THEN during a data insert would correctly insert/set the "FK" values in that child table to the parent table. As long as the link master/child settings were correctly setup (but no actual relationship was setup), then the application would happy work.

If one was to migrate the data to say SQL server? Well, since the PK autonumbers are NOT touched during this up-load process - then all relationships and their data would ALSO make a valid trip up to SQL server.

However, in the case of SharePoint? Autonumbers for ALL tables are and will and in most cases are re-generated!!!!

But, this tends to not be a problem if you up-sized the data using Access. It has built in SharePoint support, and say if a parent reocrd goes up from Access to sharepoint and the PK id is changed? No probem, since if you REALLY did setup,and you REALLY did have a relatonship setup, then the migration process is smart enough to go find the child reocrds, and update the FK values. But of course the migration process can ONLY do this magic trick if you KNOWS about the realationship.

Another simple example?
Say we have a simple form, and we have a SMIPLE combo box to pick say favor color.

tbColors
ID    (Auto number PK).
Color  (text color).

So, so now we have a simple form, and we dropped in a combo box. When we choose a simple color like "red" or "blue" from the combo, we of course are saving the "pk" id from the above table.

Now for a LOT of simple tables like above, never used, or bothered with setting up a realtonship. (no need - just a few choices from a combo box).

And if you were up-size data to sql server?  Again, this would work fine - no problem at all.

However, if you up-size to SharePoint? You REALLY but REALLY better have setup a relationship even for this simple silly little combo box. Again, the reason is simple. When that simple table of pick list values goes up to SharePoint, the autonumber PK id's will change. And thus for any other table that used that simple pick list? You have and MUST have setup in your relationships window that this was in fact the relationships - and again, the reason is re-numbering of autonumbers.

So for ANY relationships that used PK and FK values? They MUST in ALL cases when using SharePoint MUST have been defined in the access data tables (relationships window) BEFORE you transfer that data. And again, the reason is simple - during a up-load process to SharePoint, autonumbers WILL CHANGE!!! And since they change, then any other dependent table that uses those PK values (as a FK) MUST have been part of a defined relationship. If they are not defined before migration to SharePoint, then a change in a PK value will NOT tell SharePoint to go and find and correctly update all of the "child" records or so called FK values.

So, the first question to ask is did this break in related numbers occur a long time ago (at migration time), or did this break occur due to some bad code, or the wrong values having been selected?

So, migration of related data to SharePoint is a "delicate" operation, and the main reason of course is that the related tables MUCH have been setup as enforced relationships BEFORE you migrate. If such relationships were not strict defined, then during the migration process then the relation of data based on those PK/FK values will break at that migration time.

Now, it could be a simple issue that this sub form in question does not have the correct link master/child settings - that's the first thing to check.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  This non-profit does not have a SQL server available, so we are forced to use SharePoint.  I think you've given me good info to work with, and I thank you.  I'll come back and post what I found out.   I suspect the autonumbering and the foreign key assignments.

Comment: it may well be that you simple messed up the link master/child for the sub form. Using share point is fine - it is able to do relational database operations - it was not designed as a true relational database, but it can handle PK and FK operations quite well (it does not for example support text based PK's or text based FK's - they have to be numbers. So for a huge number of related tables, SharePoint will struggle with that - but for a few tables, then it can work quite well.